# Mysql join with limits on joined table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return a limited of number of products per brand. The tables are

brands:
`id`, `name`

products: 
`id`, `brand_id`, `name`

What I am trying to achieve is a query that will output brands.name and products_name 10 times for each brand.

I have tried joining the two tables but when it comes to applying the limit I can't see the next step. Is this possible or will I have to opt to do the brand query first and then query again on a foreach this being more processor intensive?

Comment: It would be useful if you can post the query you are trying

Comment: @lloiacono I don't have an attempted other than a standard `JOIN`, when I apply `LIMIT 10` It limits the brands, I need some way to `LIMIT` the products per brand

Comment: mySQL doesn't have analytical functions which would make this easier; or outer apply... yet.  so you have to use the user variables to generate a rownumber and restart the numbering when the brand changes.  then it's a simple matter of filtering where the number is less than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get 10 records per product from the second table by the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT id, brand_id, name, @n := IF(@r = brand_id, @n + 1, 1) AS rownum,
    @r := brand_id
    FROM product, (SELECT @r := 0, @n := 0) a
    ORDER BY brand_id, id
    ) a
WHERE a.rownum <= 10;
```

And `join` it with `brand` table, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM brand b
JOIN (SELECT * 
    FROM(
        SELECT id, brand_id, name, @n := IF(@r = brand_id, @n + 1, 1) AS rownum,
        @r := brand_id
        FROM product, (SELECT @r := 0, @n := 0) a
        ORDER BY brand_id, id
        ) a
    WHERE a.rownum <= 10
) p on b.id = p.brand_id;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76f580/1/0)**.

Comment: This does answer my question and it works. On looking into it this might not be the easiest or best solution as I'll still have to format the results to get them how I want. Anyway, given accepted answer.